# Problem with JS when passing a model to View .net core 2.1

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

When my client edits data, I pass to view a model, an item in my product name has the ' character, this causes my JS to break and it does not finish loading the data.

My controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(long id)
        {
           
            try
            {
                var model= await myClient.GetModel(id);
           
                ViewData["Title"] = "Title";
                return View("Register", model);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View("Error", new ResponseViewModel(ex));
            }
        }
```

My model has a list of products whose name has '

[Consle of Navigator here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8IMu.png)

View

```
@model API.Client.Models.MyModel
```

Has anyone come across this problem? I have no idea how to solve it.
I tried to replace the item's description by placing an escape character (' ) but it didn't work

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem? If not, can you share your JS code so that we can troubleshoot the issue more specificly.

Answer (score 0):

To get the model correctly in JS, you need to serialize the model correctly.

We usually get the model like this:

```
@model Movie
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
<body>
    <h1>Display Model Value</h1>
    <p id="product-id"></p>
    <p id="product-title"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Get the model as a JSON string
        var model = @Json.Serialize(Model);
        document.getElementById("product-id").innerText = "Product ID: " + model.id;
        document.getElementById("product-title").innerText = "Product Title: " + model.title;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

If you directly get the model in JS through @Model.xxx, character ' can not be recognized correctly. \' or stringify() are both invalid.